# Is this construction already a contradiction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

Let's say we have $\ell^p$ for $p>2$ and $\ell^2 \subsetneq \ell^p$. Let $U$ be a closed subspace of $\ell^2$. Is it possible that $U$ is isomorphic to $\ell^p$ as a Banach space?- I hardly think so. I already know that if $U$ was a closed subspace of $\ell^p$ it cannot be isomorphic to $\ell^2$ by Pitt's theorem, but this one looks even easier, but I cannot prove it though.

Comment: It follows from a more general version of Pitt's Theorem, c.f. Kalton and Albiac's text [page 32](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA32&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), that no infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_q$ if $p\ne q$, $1\le p,q<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra but in your theorem they look at closed subspaces of $\ell^p$ and not of $\ell^2$. Apparently, it is the other way around.

Comment: If you have an isomorphism from $U$ to a subspace of $\ell_p$, its inverse is a bounded operator from a closed subspace of $\ell_p$ to $\ell_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any bounded linear operator from $l^2$ to $l^p$, is compact, and thus cannot be an isomorphism, so no isomorphism can exist between them. So they cannot be Isomorphic.

Let us try to make one, let $L:U\to l^p$ defined by $L_x(y)=\sum_nx_ny_n$, for $x\in U,y\in l^p$, here $L_x(y)=\langle x,y\rangle_{l^2}$, thus $|L_x(y)|=|\langle x,y\rangle_{l^2}|\leq\|x\|_{l^2}\|y\|_{l^p}$, since $x$ is fixed for each $L_x$, we see that the operator is bounded, and takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), which is finite dimensional, so the operator is of finite rank and thus is compact.

Comment: my question was not whether $\ell^2$ and $\ell^p$ are isomorphic. It is whether $\ell^p$ and a subspace of $\ell^2$ can be isomorphic.

Comment: Yep, edited it now

Comment: how do you know that a linear operator needs to have exactly this form?

Comment: reisz representation theorem

Comment: this is for hilbert spaces, not for $\ell^p$.

Comment: also, basically this holds and says that $l^2$ is not isomorphic to  $l^p$, and since $l^2\subsetneq l^p$, it holds for the smaller subset $U$.

Comment: I know, but since we are going from $l^2$, which is a hilbert space, we can use it.

Comment: Riesz representation theorem says $\ell^2 $' is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2$. How do we get from this to your map?

Comment: sorry,  your tex went wrong above

Comment: The formal identity from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_3$ is bounded but not compact.

Comment: it also states that a for all elements $x\in H$, $H$ a hilbert space, $x$ induces a linear functional $L_x(y)=\langle x,y\rangle$

Comment: @DavidMitra the identity does not have a finite dimensional range, which is why it is not compact.

Comment: My comment was with regards to your statement "Any bounded linear operator from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^p$, is compact". This is false for $p>2$.

Comment: you are correct, sorry, it holds from $l^p$ to $l^2$.